# Openning a new form from a tab

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I'm creating forms with VBA/Access to access my database.

In a form, I have a *lst_sinistres* listbox that displays the results of my SQL query and when I doubleclick on one of the results it opens me another form with thanks to this code

```
Private Sub lst_sinistres_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.OpenForm "F_SINISTRE_MRH", acNormal, , , , , Me.lst_sinistres.Value

End Sub
```

I wanted to change my form, and add tabs to make it more ergonomic. So I placed my *lst_sinistres* listbox inside a tab.
The problem is that when I doubleclick on one of the results in this listbox (now placed in the tab), the form *F_SINISTRE_MRH* does not open.

Does someone have an idea of ​​where the problem might come?

Thank you

Comment: check if lst_sinistres control have DblClick property in pallete

Comment: Ok.. I just rewrote the code by selecting the DblClick proprety and it worked. Don't know why. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A quirk of VBA control events is that event *code* can become detached from the control *object*. Things that cause this tend to be re-naming controls and copy/pasting similar code between controls. To move your listbox onto a tab control you needed to cut and paste it temporarily. That broke the link between the written code and the object name. When the code and object are properly linked, **[Event Procedure]** shows up in the property sheet (as suggested by @4dmonster).

If you are in the VBA editor, choosing Debug->Compile will search through all the code and re-link event code with like-named controls. This step is worth a try before re-writing because you may end up with orphan blocks of

```
Private Sub OldControlName_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
MsgBox "Why don't I work anymore?"
End Sub
```

that are treated as Form-level subroutines that just happen to never be called.
pT